# Spin tool is not shown in toolbar when trying to spin a curve

Tags: modeling, interface, bezier-curves

I am trying to find the spin tool in Blender version 2.68. It's not on the left panel. Should I check something in the preferences?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's there for me.. Are you in edit mode? (You can also access the spin tool with `Alt+R`)

Comment: yes, in edit mode. neither Alr+R not working

Answer (score 7):

The spin tool does not work with curves, it's specifically made for meshes. There aren't really any alternatives other than rotating around the 3D cursor.

To rotate around the 3D cursor:

1. Press <kbd>.</kbd> to set the pivot point to the 3d cursor.
2. Position the cursor at the center of the turn.
3. Extrude <kbd>e</kbd> and rotate the curve.

   [image]
4. Tweak the handles so it's curved:

   [image]

If you don't care if the object is a curve you could convert it to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>) and work with it from there.

Comment: @user1481 If this answer has answered your question, consider [accepting it](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 7):

The spin tool is for mesh objects.

For curves you can get the same result using two curves, one for the outline and one for the 'spinning'. The outline curve is set as the bevel object to the spinning curve. For a 360 degree spin a BezierCircle is a good starting point.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found this [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33410/cant-find-spin-menu-to-create-a-rotational-object) -- I think you need to convert the Bezier curve to a mesh (Alt+C --> Mesh from Curve), then Tab to enter Edit mode, then A to select all points, then you can use the Spin command. I'm in a similar boat as you, and this worked for me.

[image]