# Can't find Spin Menu to create a rotational object

Tags: modeling

I want to create a rotational solid. I've just created a bezier curve, and i saw many tutorials use the "SPIN" function in the left menu.
I tried looking at it but whitout success.
Where can i find it? I have to enable it in the add-ons menu?
I'm in edit mode with TOP ORTHO visual.
(Blender 2.75 RC1)
Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spin function works on vertex, while the bezier curves are based on control points. You could transform the curve in mesh (Alt C, mesh from curve) and then use the spin function, but you would loose the interactivity of the modelling process; so the best way, with bezier curves, is to use a screw modifier, instead.
Choose the right axis (in my example z axis).

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful, I think, if you could mention why this option isn't appearing for curve objects instead of just showing an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that you are selecting a Mesh not a curve

-If you have a curve, you can go to Object menu then Convert to, or use Alt + C

*Hint: you can then check the 'keep original' check box to the bottom left, if you need not to lose the curve